# What kind of tasks Node.js is not suitable for?

Tags: node.js, scripting

It is well known that [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) ([Google's V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/)) due to its non-blocking architecture can effectively handle thousands of requests per second being used as a web server. There's also a huge number of IO intensive tasks that Node can easily cope with. I would like to know if every server task that we used to solve with Perl, Python or Ruby could be written in Node.js to run almost that fast. Or there's a particular sort of tasks Node.js should be avoided for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*JavaScript* itself should be avoided for computation intensive tasks (just like Perl, python and ruby should not do computation intensive tasks). These should be doing in C/C++ and possibly injected into node as a C++ addon

node.js should be avoided for *blocking IO* (You never need blocking IO, just do it non-blocking).

Other then that node.js is not a friendly environment for mission critical code (neither is Perl, python or ruby). For the record mission critical means, if your code breaks, people die.

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer. What kind of environment do you consider mission critical BTW?

Comment: @nab, you may want to read [Best language for safety-critical software](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243387/best-language-for-safety-critical-software) ;)